# GitLab - Fixing merge conflicts

Tags: php, laravel, git, gitlab, phpstorm

We have multiple branches `master`, `development` & `branchTaskNumber`, we take the `brachTaskNumber` from the `master` branch, and when finish we merge it into the `development` branch.
When we create merge requests GitLab shows there are merge conflicts.

We decide to pull the `branchTaskNumber` branch and fix conflicts but GitLab shows again merge conflicts.

We are trying to fix conflicts with GitLab by Resolve conflicts button, but sometimes it didn't achieve the result.

And I take a look at the merge conflicts it's like whitespace, lines, the PHP array keys order.

Any answers?

Comment: Using `master` and `development ` branches is harder than just using one `main` branch. Trunk-based development is the modern approach for branching. Merge to `main` as soon as you can and more often.

Comment: To resolve conflicts, you can pull branch to your local machine, resolve conflicts manually, commit, and push.

Comment: _we take the brachTaskNumber from the master branch, and when finish we merge it into the development branch_ General practice is to merge the branch back to it's parent branch.

Comment: Ideally you'd branch out from development, merge back into development and then merge into master (depending on company policy, typically to prepare for a production release)

Comment: In fact, I have already taken these steps, but the GitLab strategy differs in finding the conflicts, I have made a pull branch to the local machine and I fixed the conflicts and made a push but there are still conflicts on the GitLab
Knowing that I merged the 2 Branches into the Local Machine and there were no conflicts
@VladDX

Answer (score 1):

> we take the brachTaskNumber from the master branch, and when finish we merge it into the development branch.

First, rebase locally (on your machine) that branch on top of the target branch (`develop`)

```bash
git switch brachTaskNumber 
git rebase develop
```

You will resolve all conflicts, *then* you can make your pull request (or force push if you had an existing pull request, which will be updated automatically)

Since all conflicts are resolved locally, your pull request won't show any conflict on GitLab side.